# OrientDB : custom sort order for OIndexNotUnique

Tags: orientdb

I am using the graph api and i have created an index NOT_UNIQUE on a string property.

```
entryVersionType.createProperty('property', OType.STRING).createIndex(INDEX_TYPE.NOTUNIQUE);
```

Now i would like to configure the index sort algorithm. I don't want to use the default sort order (`String::compareTo(Object)`).

Is there a way to register a custom `comparator` ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of the possibility to change the `java.util.Comparator` used by the Index Engine. However, you are can create your own [Index Engine](http://orientdb.gitbooks.io/orientdb-manual/content/orientdb.wiki/Custom-Index-Engine.html).